# Using winapi and opengl functions(c++) in Qt application (wndproc)

Tags: winapi, opengl, qt5

guys! We have working Project win32 with winapi functions which draws cube. We create a WNDCLASS and opengl context there for drawing. Can we use same functions like WinMain and WinProc in Qt for windows message processing?
We tried to do it, using hwnd of the window, without creating WNDCLASS. But after that we have just window without drawing area and rendering.
We should use winapi functions for next unloading theese functions in dll and use them in python and delphi.

Here is cpp-file
http://rgho.st/7KwpPfxZG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QT is a cross platform framework and takes care of hiding away things like WinMain and WindowProcs and instead provides a platform neutral abstraction.

Fortunately OpenGL is directly supported by QT - and they even have a page showing how to integrate OpenGL with QT here:

[QT GUI OpenGL Window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html)